# Basic Authentication not found in IIS 6.0

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2007

For Sharepoint Central Admin to work I need to enable Basic Authentication in IIS 6.0
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/forums/p/2287/2881.aspx
For some reason I am not able to find it in IIS 6.0 on my machine.

I See only Anonymous authentication, ASP.net Impersonation, Forms Authentication.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you running Windows XP/Windows Vista or Windows Server?

Comment: I am running Windows Vista Home Premium edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have installed all the authentication components for IIS.

Go to add remove programs -> Add remove windows features

there under IIS i will recommend you to check all the options and install a fully blown iis server, however if you can understand what each element means, you can check the components which will add all the authentication features for iis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be admin on your machine to change this setting.  If you are, follow [these instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/abbca505-6f63-4267-aac1-1ea89d861eb4.mspx?mfr=true) and you should be fine.